# Why does my Kenmore washing machine not move out of the wash cycle?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

While doing laundry this weekend, it seemed like the washer was taking a very long time to get through 1 regular load. I finally went to check on it and found that it never moved from the very first wash cycle. I am able to move the cycle knob manually to go through the rest of the cycles, but it won't move on its own.

I have a Kenmore 500 series washer.

Comment: Have you contacted Kenmore customer service?

Comment: @Tester101 I have not. This is my first major appliance problem, so I didn't know how helpful they would be over the phone or what to expect. Since it's no longer under warranty I assumed they would just want to send someone out first.

Comment: Did you read the manual? Has the washer filled/drained as it should have?  If the water supply is turned off or clogged, the washer will not fill and will never move to the next cycle. If the washer does not drain properly, it will not move to the next cycle.

Comment: Start of cycle it fills. If I move the cycle knob manually it does drain, spin, basically go through a normal cycle as it should. So I see no issues with fill/drain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably the timer mechanism itself.  You can [enter your model here](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/brands-products/Kenmore-Parts/Washer-Parts) and get an idea of part cost:

Comment: $150 later :( a new timer fixed the issue. Thanks